# startLocalOnlyHotspot and create hotspot programaticaly

Tags: android, kotlin, garbage-collection, android-12, hotspot

### startLocalOnlyHotspot and create hotspot programaticaly

I am trying to create a hotspot programmatically similar to [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vinhashapp.freewifihotspotportable&hl=en&gl=US) my problem is hotspot
create and immediately disappear

Here is the code I am using:

```
   private val wifiManager: WifiManager by lazy {
    (applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager)
}



   startLocalOnlyHotspot(object : WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback() {
            override fun onStarted(reservation: WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotReservation) {
                super.onStarted(reservation)
            }

            override fun onStopped() {
                super.onStopped()
            }

            override fun onFailed(reason: Int) {
                super.onFailed(reason)
            }
        }, Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()))
```

I have also tried this code with foreground service and WorkManager but it did not work. When I check my logcat, I see that the hotspot is created but disappears immediately with the following error message:

> **System  resource failed to call close.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep the `reservation` object as a field like this :

```
private WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotReservation reservation
```